# Java Hadoop inserting and query large data in JSON Format

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a requirement to build a system with Java and Hadoop to handle large data processing (in JSON Format). The system I'm going to create is including insert data to the file storage (whether it is HDFS or database) and query the processed data

I have a big picture of using Hadoop MapReduce to query the data that the user want.
But one thing that makes me confuse is how should I insert the data. Should I use HDFS and inserting the file using Java with Hadoop API? Or is it better to use another tools (e.g. HBase, Relational Database, NoSQL Database) to insert the data so that Hadoop MapReduce will take the input data from another tools that I will be used?

Please advise.

Thank you very much

Comment: It depends where your "processed data" is coming from? If it is just some file(s) then you can user `hadoop fs -put <local-file> <dest-file>`. If it is coming from another system then you can use other tools such as Kafka/Flume/Spark/etc

Comment: Actually,the big picture is my java app will write log files in JSON format (server side on wep apps,about 200 logging processes / sec). Map reducing the logged files will be done separatedly,i.e. manual (not through some feature in the app). I read about writing to HDFS using java with hadoop API,but is it thread-safe to write simultaneously to one file using hadoop API? Or should I use another tool to write the log file?

Comment: No it will not be thread-safe, multiple processes writing to a single file will bring a world of pain. You can either 1) Manage your own threading. 2) Have a look at [Apache Flume](https://flume.apache.org/index.html). It has a [HTTP Source](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#http-source) or 3) Write out 200 files then reduce on them

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Very clear.
I want to ask for your opinion, how about using HBase as an alternative?
Thank you very much

Comment: No problem at all. TBH I have no experience of HBase, but I think HBase maps more to a database use case (I may be wrong though). The architecture that I am currently using is a REST webservice sending messages to RabbitMQ, then using Flume to tee off the messages and write into HDFS.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use HDFS/HIVE/JSONSerde approach.

The solution outline would look like.

1. Store your JSON data on HDFS.
2. Create external tables using hive and use jsonSerde to map json data to columns of your table.
3. Query your data using hiveQL.

In the above solution, Since hive is schema-on-read, Your json data will be parsed every time when you query the tables.

But if you want to parse the data once and if you have data arriving in batches (weekly, monthly), it would be good to parse the data once and create a staging table. which can be used for frequent querying to avoid repetitive parsing by serde.

I have an example created at :[Hadoopgig](http://hadoopgig.blogspot.com/2017/02/queryparse-massive-json-data-on.html)